# Label doesn't show text

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uilabel

When I launch my app, tap on a cell in my RootViewController  (`AufnahmeIstTableViewController`), it opens up my DetailViewController (`AufnahmeISTDetailTableViewController`).When I then tap on cell, it should open a third ViewController (`AufnahmeIstDetailDetailViewController`). My app works like in this tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=99Ssk1-HUq4

But when I tap on a cell and open my third view, the labels on my third view controller don't display any text as declared in the code.

What do I have to change? Here are all my files:

Here is my AufnahmeIstTableViewController.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AufnahmeIstTableViewController : UITableViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *categoryArray;
@end
```

Here's my AufnahmeIstTableViewController.m file:

```
#import "AufnahmeIstTableViewController.h"
#import "AufnahmeISTDetailTableViewController.h"

@interface AufnahmeIstTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation AufnahmeIstTableViewController
@synthesize categoryArray;


-(NSMutableArray *)categoryArray
{
    if (!categoryArray)

    {
        categoryArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }
    return categoryArray;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.categoryArray addObject:@"Gesetze"];
    [self.categoryArray addObject:@"Verordnungen"];
    [self.categoryArray addObject:@"Technische Regeln"];
    [self.categoryArray addObject:@"Berufsgenossenschaft"];
    [self.categoryArray addObject:@"Management"];
    [self.categoryArray addObject:@"Personal"];
    [self.categoryArray addObject:@"Vertrieb"];
    [self.categoryArray addObject:@"Kunden"];
    [self.categoryArray addObject:@"Lieferanten"];
    [self.categoryArray addObject:@"Arbeitsumgebung"];
    [self.categoryArray addObject:@"Produktion"];
    [self.categoryArray addObject:@"Produkte"];
    [self.categoryArray addObject:@"Messmittel"];
    [self.categoryArray addObject:@"Informationssicherheit"];
    [self.categoryArray addObject:@"Rechnungswesen"];
    [self.categoryArray addObject:@"Dritte"];

    [self setTitle:@"Ist-Aufnahme"];


    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return self.categoryArray.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.textLabel.text = self.categoryArray [indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    AufnahmeISTDetailTableViewController *categories = [[AufnahmeISTDetailTableViewController alloc]init];

    if ([[self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Gesetze"])
        categories.istAufnahmeInt = 0;

    if ([[self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Verordnungen"])
        categories.istAufnahmeInt = 1;

    if ([[self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Technische Regeln"])
        categories.istAufnahmeInt = 2;

    if ([[self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Berufsgenossenschaft"])
        categories.istAufnahmeInt = 3;

    if ([[self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Management"])
        categories.istAufnahmeInt = 4;

    if ([[self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Personal"])
        categories.istAufnahmeInt = 5;

    if ([[self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Vertrieb"])
        categories.istAufnahmeInt = 6;

    if ([[self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Kunden"])
        categories.istAufnahmeInt = 7;

    if ([[self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Lieferanten"])
        categories.istAufnahmeInt = 8;

    if ([[self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Arbeitsumgebung"])
        categories.istAufnahmeInt = 9;

    if ([[self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Produktion"])
        categories.istAufnahmeInt = 10;

    if ([[self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Produkte"])
        categories.istAufnahmeInt = 11;

    if ([[self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Messmittel"])
        categories.istAufnahmeInt = 12;

    if ([[self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Informationssicherheit"])
        categories.istAufnahmeInt = 13;

    if ([[self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Rechnungswesen"])
        categories.istAufnahmeInt = 14;

    if ([[self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Dritte"])
        categories.istAufnahmeInt = 15;


    [categories setTitle:[self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        //[self.navigationController pushViewController:categories animated:YES];
     [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
#pragma mark - Navigation
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"DetailView"])
{
    AufnahmeISTDetailTableViewController *controller = (AufnahmeISTDetailTableViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    if ([[self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row] isEqual:@"Gesetze"])
        controller.istAufnahmeInt = 0;

    if ([[self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row] isEqual:@"Verordnungen"])
        controller.istAufnahmeInt = 1;

    if ([[self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row] isEqual:@"Technische Regeln"])
        controller.istAufnahmeInt = 2;

    if ([[self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row] isEqual:@"Berufsgenossenschaft"])
        controller.istAufnahmeInt = 3;

    if ([[self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row] isEqual:@"Management"])
        controller.istAufnahmeInt = 4;

    if ([[self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row] isEqual:@"Personal"])
        controller.istAufnahmeInt = 5;

    if ([[self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row] isEqual:@"Vertrieb"])
        controller.istAufnahmeInt = 6;

    if ([[self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row] isEqual:@"Kunden"])
        controller.istAufnahmeInt = 7;

    if ([[self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row] isEqual:@"Lieferanten"])
        controller.istAufnahmeInt = 8;

    if ([[self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row] isEqual:@"Arbeitsumgebung"])
        controller.istAufnahmeInt = 9;

    if ([[self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row] isEqual:@"Produktion"])
        controller.istAufnahmeInt = 10;

    if ([[self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row] isEqual:@"Produkte"])
        controller.istAufnahmeInt = 11;

    if ([[self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row] isEqual:@"Messmittel"])
        controller.istAufnahmeInt = 12;

    if ([[self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row] isEqual:@"Informationssicherheit"])
        controller.istAufnahmeInt = 13;

    if ([[self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row] isEqual:@"Rechnungswesen"])
        controller.istAufnahmeInt = 14;

    if ([[self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row] isEqual:@"Dritte"])
        controller.istAufnahmeInt = 15;

    [controller setTitle:[self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row]];
}
}


@end
```

Here's my AufnahmeISTDetailTableViewController.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AufnahmeIstTableViewController.h"
#import "AufnahmeIstDetailDetailViewController.h"

@interface AufnahmeISTDetailTableViewController : UITableViewController {
    NSMutableArray *gesetzeArray;
    NSMutableArray *verordnungenArray;
    NSMutableArray *technischeregelnArray;
    NSMutableArray *berufsgenossenschaftArray;
    NSMutableArray *managementArray;
    NSMutableArray *personalArray;
    NSMutableArray *vertriebArray;
    NSMutableArray *kundenArray;
    NSMutableArray *lieferantenArray;
    NSMutableArray *arbeitsumgebungArray;
    NSMutableArray *produktionArray;
    NSMutableArray *produkteArray;
    NSMutableArray *messmittelArray;
    NSMutableArray *informationssicherheitArray;
    NSMutableArray *rechnungswesenArray;
    NSMutableArray *dritteArray;


}
@property int istAufnahmeInt;
@property AufnahmeIstTableViewController *categories;

-(void)makeData;


@end
```

And here's my AufnahmeISTDetailTableViewController.m file:

```
#import "AufnahmeISTDetailTableViewController.h"
#import "AufnahmeIstTableViewController.h"
#import "AufnahmeIstDetailDetailViewController.h"

@interface AufnahmeISTDetailTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation AufnahmeISTDetailTableViewController
@synthesize istAufnahmeInt;
@synthesize categories;


- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
    [self makeData];

}
-(void)makeData
{
    gesetzeArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    verordnungenArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    technischeregelnArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    berufsgenossenschaftArray= [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    managementArray= [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    personalArray= [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    vertriebArray= [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    kundenArray= [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    lieferantenArray= [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    arbeitsumgebungArray= [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    produktionArray= [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    produkteArray= [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    messmittelArray= [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    informationssicherheitArray= [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    rechnungswesenArray= [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    dritteArray= [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    //Gesetze
        [gesetzeArray addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Bundesdatenschutzgesetz",@"name",@"Bundesdatenschutzgesetz wurde gedrückt", @"description", nil]];

    //Verordnungen
        [verordnungenArray addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Verordnung zur arbeitsmedizinischen Vorsorge – ArbMedVV",@"name",@"Verordnung zur arbeitsmedizinischen Vorsorge – ArbMedVV wurde gedrückt",@"description", nil]];

    //Technische Regeln
        [technischeregelnArray addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Technische Regeln",@"name",@"Technische Regeln wurde gedrückt", @"description", nil]];
    //Berufsgenossenschaft
        [berufsgenossenschaftArray addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Berufsgenossenschaft",@"name",@"Berufsgenossenschaft wurde gedrückt", @"description", nil]];
    //Management
        [managementArray addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Bundesdatenschutzgesetz",@"name",@"Bundesdatenschutzgesetz wurde gedrückt", @"description", nil]];
    //Personal
        [personalArray addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Bundesdatenschutzgesetz",@"name",@"Bundesdatenschutzgesetz wurde gedrückt", @"description", nil]];
    //Vertrieb
        [vertriebArray addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Bundesdatenschutzgesetz",@"name",@"Bundesdatenschutzgesetz wurde gedrückt", @"description", nil]];
    //Kunden
        [kundenArray addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Bundesdatenschutzgesetz",@"name",@"Bundesdatenschutzgesetz wurde gedrückt", @"description", nil]];
    //Lieferanten
        [lieferantenArray addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Bundesdatenschutzgesetz",@"name",@"Bundesdatenschutzgesetz wurde gedrückt", @"description", nil]];
    //Arbeitsumgebung
        [arbeitsumgebungArray addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Bundesdatenschutzgesetz",@"name",@"Bundesdatenschutzgesetz wurde gedrückt", @"description", nil]];
    //Produktion
        [produktionArray addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Bundesdatenschutzgesetz",@"name",@"Bundesdatenschutzgesetz wurde gedrückt", @"description", nil]];
    //Produkte
        [produkteArray addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Bundesdatenschutzgesetz",@"name",@"Bundesdatenschutzgesetz wurde gedrückt", @"description", nil]];
    //Messmittel
        [messmittelArray addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Bundesdatenschutzgesetz",@"name",@"Bundesdatenschutzgesetz wurde gedrückt", @"description", nil]];
    //Informationssicherheit
        [informationssicherheitArray addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Bundesdatenschutzgesetz",@"name",@"Bundesdatenschutzgesetz wurde gedrückt", @"description", nil]];
    //Rechnungswesen
        [rechnungswesenArray addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Bundesdatenschutzgesetz",@"name",@"Bundesdatenschutzgesetz wurde gedrückt", @"description", nil]];
    //Dritte
        [dritteArray addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Bundesdatenschutzgesetz",@"name",@"Bundesdatenschutzgesetz wurde gedrückt", @"description", nil]];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    if (self.istAufnahmeInt == 0)
    {
        return [gesetzeArray count];
    }
    if (self.istAufnahmeInt == 1)
    {
        return [verordnungenArray count];
    }
    if (self.istAufnahmeInt == 2)
    {
        return [technischeregelnArray count];
    }
    if (self.istAufnahmeInt == 3)
    {
        return [berufsgenossenschaftArray count];
    }
    if (self.istAufnahmeInt == 4)
    {
        return [managementArray count];
    }
    if (self.istAufnahmeInt == 5)
    {
        return [personalArray count];
    }
    if (self.istAufnahmeInt == 6)
    {
        return [vertriebArray count];
    }
    if (self.istAufnahmeInt == 7)
    {
        return [kundenArray count];
    }
    if (self.istAufnahmeInt == 8)
    {
        return [lieferantenArray count];
    }
    if (self.istAufnahmeInt == 9)
    {
        return [arbeitsumgebungArray count];
    }
    if (self.istAufnahmeInt == 10)
    {
        return [produktionArray count];
    }
    if (self.istAufnahmeInt == 11)
    {
        return [produkteArray count];
    }
    if (self.istAufnahmeInt == 12)
    {
        return [messmittelArray count];
    }
    if (self.istAufnahmeInt == 13)
    {
        return [informationssicherheitArray count];
    }
    if (self.istAufnahmeInt == 14)
    {
        return [rechnungswesenArray count];
    }
    if (self.istAufnahmeInt == 15)
    {
        return [dritteArray count];
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];

}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier1 = @"DetailCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier1 forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier1];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
                if (self.istAufnahmeInt == 0) cell.textLabel.text = [[gesetzeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];
                if (self.istAufnahmeInt == 1) cell.textLabel.text = [[verordnungenArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name" ];
                if (self.istAufnahmeInt == 2) cell.textLabel.text = [[technischeregelnArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];
                if (self.istAufnahmeInt == 3) cell.textLabel.text = [[berufsgenossenschaftArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];
                if (self.istAufnahmeInt == 4) cell.textLabel.text = [[managementArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];
                if (self.istAufnahmeInt == 5) cell.textLabel.text = [[personalArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];
                if (self.istAufnahmeInt == 6) cell.textLabel.text = [[vertriebArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];
                if (self.istAufnahmeInt == 7) cell.textLabel.text = [[kundenArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];
                if (self.istAufnahmeInt == 8) cell.textLabel.text = [[lieferantenArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];
                if (self.istAufnahmeInt == 9) cell.textLabel.text = [[arbeitsumgebungArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];
                if (self.istAufnahmeInt == 10) cell.textLabel.text = [[produktionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];
                if (self.istAufnahmeInt == 11) cell.textLabel.text = [[produkteArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];
                if (self.istAufnahmeInt == 12) cell.textLabel.text = [[messmittelArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];
                if (self.istAufnahmeInt == 13) cell.textLabel.text = [[informationssicherheitArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];
                if (self.istAufnahmeInt == 14) cell.textLabel.text = [[rechnungswesenArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];
                if (self.istAufnahmeInt == 15) cell.textLabel.text = [[dritteArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];


    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    AufnahmeIstDetailDetailViewController *aufnahmeistDetail =[[AufnahmeIstDetailDetailViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"AufnahmeIstDetailDetailViewController"  bundle:nil];

    if (istAufnahmeInt == 0)
    {
        aufnahmeistDetail.titelString = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[[gesetzeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"]];
        aufnahmeistDetail.title = [[gesetzeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];
    }

    if (istAufnahmeInt == 1)
    {
        aufnahmeistDetail.titelString = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[[verordnungenArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"]];
        aufnahmeistDetail.title = [[verordnungenArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];
    }

    if (istAufnahmeInt == 2)
    {
        aufnahmeistDetail.titelString = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[[technischeregelnArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"]];
        aufnahmeistDetail.title = [[technischeregelnArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];
    }

    if (istAufnahmeInt == 3)
    {
        aufnahmeistDetail.titelString = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[[berufsgenossenschaftArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"]];
        aufnahmeistDetail.title = [[berufsgenossenschaftArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];
    }

    if (istAufnahmeInt == 4)
    {
        aufnahmeistDetail.titelString = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[[managementArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"]];
        aufnahmeistDetail.title = [[managementArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];
    }

    if (istAufnahmeInt == 5)
    {
        aufnahmeistDetail.titelString = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[[personalArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"]];
        aufnahmeistDetail.title = [[personalArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];
    }

    if (istAufnahmeInt == 6)
    {
        aufnahmeistDetail.titelString = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[[vertriebArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"]];
        aufnahmeistDetail.title = [[vertriebArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];
    }

    if (istAufnahmeInt == 7)
    {
        aufnahmeistDetail.titelString = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[[kundenArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"]];
        aufnahmeistDetail.title = [[kundenArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];
    }

    if (istAufnahmeInt == 8)
    {
        aufnahmeistDetail.titelString = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[[lieferantenArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"]];
        aufnahmeistDetail.title = [[lieferantenArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];
    }

    if (istAufnahmeInt == 9)
    {
        aufnahmeistDetail.titelString = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[[arbeitsumgebungArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"]];
        aufnahmeistDetail.title = [[arbeitsumgebungArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];
    }

    if (istAufnahmeInt == 10)
    {
        aufnahmeistDetail.titelString = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[[produktionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"]];
        aufnahmeistDetail.title = [[produktionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];
    }

    if (istAufnahmeInt == 11)
    {
        aufnahmeistDetail.titelString = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[[produkteArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"]];
        aufnahmeistDetail.title = [[produkteArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];
    }

    if (istAufnahmeInt == 12)
    {
        aufnahmeistDetail.titelString = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[[messmittelArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"]];
        aufnahmeistDetail.title = [[messmittelArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];
    }

    if (istAufnahmeInt == 13)
    {
        aufnahmeistDetail.titelString = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[[informationssicherheitArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"]];
        aufnahmeistDetail.title = [[informationssicherheitArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];
    }

    if (istAufnahmeInt == 14)
    {
        aufnahmeistDetail.titelString = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[[rechnungswesenArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"]];
        aufnahmeistDetail.title = [[rechnungswesenArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];
    }

    if (istAufnahmeInt == 15)
    {
        aufnahmeistDetail.titelString = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[[dritteArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"]];
        aufnahmeistDetail.title = [[dritteArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];
    }


}
@end
```

Here's my AufnahmeISTDetailTableViewController.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AufnahmeISTDetailTableViewController.h"
@interface AufnahmeIstDetailDetailViewController : UIViewController

{
    IBOutlet UILabel *titleLabel;
    IBOutlet UILabel *textLabel;
    NSString *titelString;
    NSString *textString;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *titelString;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *textString;


@end
```

And finally, here's my AufnahmeISTDetailTableViewController.m file:

```
#import "AufnahmeIstDetailDetailViewController.h"
#import "AufnahmeISTDetailTableViewController.h"

@interface AufnahmeIstDetailDetailViewController ()

@end

@implementation AufnahmeIstDetailDetailViewController
@synthesize textString;
@synthesize titelString;

- (instancetype)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    titleLabel.text = titelString;
    textLabel.text = textString;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to just set breakpoints and ensure that your code that sets the labels is actually setting the correct string values. If you are sure about that, then there must be something wrong with your IB files (clearColor text, maybe?).

On another note, you have a horrendous amount of hardcoding in your view controllers. You should decouple your data from your views.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like it is either an in-house App or one for OBI given the Messmittel and Lieferanten arrays, but this is out of the scope and with that aside.

tilo's suggestion is correct, if you would like to get a hold of the controller through storyboard and segue to it while passing objects to it too.

Here is what I have noticed in your code, right from the very first `AufnahmeIstTableViewController.h`:

In your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` you don't actually need to check the values against a string, because your array does in fact contains those elements namely "Gesetze", "Verordnungen", "Technische Regeln", "Berufsgenossenschaft" etc.

So basically you could just to:

```
controller.istAufnahmeInt = [[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] row];
```

Or safer:

```
if([self.categoriesArray count] >= [[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] row])
{
    controller.istAufnahmeInt = [[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] row];
}
```

Now in your `prepareForSegue`:

You're basically doing the same thing there. So what you really need to do is just:

```
controller.istAufnahmeInt = categories.istAufnahmeInt;
```

So apply the same logic for your second view controller to your third using till's suggestion to pass the strings to it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: could you please send me the code I need, because I don't know what to put in where he made the three dots? @Unheilig

Answer (score 0):

in your second view controller, you are setting `titelString` and `textString` on a viewController that you don't actually show.

You need to implement `prepareForSegue:sender:` in your second view controller:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    AufnahmeIstDetailDetailViewController *aufnahmeistDetail = [segue destinationViewController];
    int selectedRow  = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row;

    aufnahmeistDetail.titleString = ...; // get the appropriate string based on the selected row
    aufnahmeistDetail.textString = ...;
}
```

Comment: so what should it look like here you put the ... ?

Comment: Get the appropriate strings just like you did in your `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method (this may then be removed)

Comment: So, is this right? That's just one example @tilo 

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    AufnahmeIstDetailDetailViewController *aufnahmeistDetail = [segue destinationViewController];
    int selectedRow  = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row;
    
    
    if (istAufnahmeInt == 0)
    {
        aufnahmeistDetail.titelString = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[[gesetzeArray objectAtIndex:selectedRow]objectForKey:@"name"]];
        aufnahmeistDetail.title = [[gesetzeArray objectAtIndex:selectedRow]objectForKey:@"name"];
    }
    }

Comment: This way you'll get what you didi in your original code. However, you do not make use of the row index, i.e. you'll get the same result no matter what row you are selecting.

Comment: So could you send me an example of what it should Look like, please? @tilo

Comment: No, this is would blow up the comments/answer. However, this is covered in (most likely) every tutorial on table views.